# Как перевести массив типа Byte в picturebox?

Tags: c#

Можно ли предать измененную последовательность типа `Byte` после записи в него JPG/BMP картинки в новый `picturebox`? Нужно ли заново передавать измененный Массив обратно в `MemoryStream`? Я попробовал следующее:

```
//Открытие FiledDialog для чтения JPG/BMP картинки
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

byte[] buff = new byte[10573];
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Заполнение pcturebox прочитанной картинкой
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    //Передача Массиву buff HEX значениями прочитанной картинкой
    buff = ms.ToArray();
}

//Печать размера buff, чтобы при следующем старте программы знать тосное значение размера buff в зависимости от конкретной картинки
Console.WriteLine(buff.Length);

//Печать значения buff
for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i += 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + "=" + buff[i].ToString("x"));
    progressBar1.Value += 1;
}

//Зачена всех значений buff значением 0xbb

for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i += 1)
{
    buff[i] = 0xbb;
}

//Перевод buff  в новый picturebox, но при старте отладчика компилятор выводит ошибку, неверные параметры
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buff));
pictureBox2.Refresh();
```

Можно ли напрямую представлять любую картинку JPG/BMP как последовательность HEX значений?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, hex - это *строковое* представление числа. И ваш код вполне представляет картинку в виде hex-значений.

Во вторых - Jpeg - это сжатая картинка. Т.е. вы печатаете не сами "значения пикселей в HEX". Вы печатаете внутреннее представление JPEG-файа, которое имеет мало общего с данными пикселей картинки.

То же самое с заменой всего подряд на 0xbb. Вы не меняете пиксели, и не перекрашиваете все в серый цвет. Вы просто берете файл и заменяете все его содержимое на одинаковые байты. Что, естественно, делает его невалидным файлом картинки.

Что должно произойти при его открытии? FromStream пытается понять, в каком формате там лежат данные - jpg/bmp/png, еще что-то - а ему в ответ 0xbb 0xbb 0xbb 0xbb. Вот он и падает.

Если вам нужно получить доступ к пикселям - и перекрасить картинку в серый, например - то вы должны работать с самим Bitmap, а не с результатом сохранения его в jpeg. Вам нужны или методы [SetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx)/[GetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx), или прямой доступ к массиву байт внутри Bitmap - [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d.aspx).